# Construir un arboles de expresiones a partir de archivo txt En c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

El problema es el siguiente:

El programa que estoy realizando, debe de hacer un árbol de expresiones , hay un archivo txt que contiene polinomios (de N grados), entonces el programa debe jalar los polinomios de archivo txt guardarlo en el árbol de expresiones y luego sacar o calcular la derivada del polinomio.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int c=0 ;          
char linea[200];  


ifstream leer_archivo("Proyecto_No1.txt",ios::in);
while(!leer_archivo.eof()){                           
leer_archivo.getline(linea,100);                      
c++;                                                 
 }
leer_archivo.close();


string *texto = new string[c];                 
c=0;
ifstream archivo("Proyecto_No1.txt",ios::in); 
while(!archivo.eof()){
 archivo.getline(linea,100);              
      texto[c]=linea;
 c++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
cout<<""<<texto[i].c_str()<<endl;         
}

 archivo.close();

getch();
return 0;

  }
```

El fragmento de código, lo que hace es tomar el archivo txt y lo guarda en un array (Polinomio), pero hacer el árbol de expresiones con los datos del array (Polinomio) y calcular la derivada no se como hacerle.
Esto es lo que contiene el archivo txt

[image: Esto es lo que contiene el archivo txt]

Así debería quedar el árbol de expresiones :(

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Cualquier sugerencia, será bienvenida.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. No es necesario incluir los agradecimientos en las preguntas, ni respuestas. Para esto existen los votos. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour].

Comment: He leído tu publicación varias veces y aún no me queda claro cuál es tu pregunta o qué problema estás encontrando: ¿No sabes calcular la derivada? ¿No sabes crear el árbol de expresiones? ¿ambas cosas?

Comment: Pregunta1: Sabes derivar con lápiz y papel. Pregunta2: sabes armar un árbol de expresion con lápiz y papel.Pregunta3:En que te ayudaría el árbol de expresion para hallar la derivada

Answer (score 0):

La estrutura que pretendes expresar es excesivamente compleja.

Un monomio cualquiera se puede representar tal que:

```
class Monomio
{
    int multiplicador;
    int potencia;

public:
    Monomio(int multiplicador, int potencia)
        : multiplicador{multiplicador}
        , potencia{potencia}
    { }

    int GetMultiplicador() const
    { return multiplicador; }

    int GetPotencia() const
    { return potencia; }

    std::string ToString(bool primero) const
    {
       std::stringstream ss;
       if (multiplicador < 0)
         ss << multiplicador;
       else
       {
           if (!primero)
               ss << '+';
           
           if ((multiplicador > 1) || (potencia ==0))
               ss << multiplicador;
       }
       if (potencia > 0)
       {
           ss << 'x';
           if (potencia > 1)
               ss << '^' << potencia;
       }

       return ss.str();
    }
};
```

Con esto, un polinomio no sería más que una lista de monomios. Así, tu primer polinomio se podría representar así:

```
std::vector<Monomio> polinomio { {3, 5}, {-2, 3}, {1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {1, 0} };
```

Es facil de verificar ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DI84mkX0wh3DZ8Cu)):

```
bool primero = true;
for (auto mono : polinomio)
{
    std::cout << mono.ToString(primero);
    primero = false;
}
```

Ya tenemos el polinomio, ahora toca derivarlo.

Quizás sería más adecuado encapsular la lista de monomios en una clase Polinomio. De esa forma podemos evitar que se nos quede un monomio vacío (multiplicador 0), o que las potencias no estén ordenadas.

La mayor parte de la lógica de esta clase quedaría fuera del ámbito de la pregunta, así que me limitaré a implementar lo básico:

```
class Polinomio
{
    std::vector<Monomio> polinomio;

public:

    void Add(Monomio monomio)
    {
        if (monomio.GetMultiplicador() == 0) return;

        if (polinomio.empty())
            polinomio.push_back(monomio);
        else
        {
            // Logica para colocar el monomio en su sitio
            // ...

            polinomio.push_back(monomio);
        }
    }

    Polinomio Derivar() const
    {
        Polinomio resultado;

        for (Monomio monomio : polinomio)
        {
            if (monomio.GetPotencia() > 0)
            {
                Monomio nuevo{
                    monomio.GetMultiplicador()*monomio.GetPotencia(),
                    monomio.GetPotencia()-1
                };

                resultado.Add(nuevo);
            }
        }

        return resultado;
    }
    
    std::string ToString() const
    {
        std::string result;
        
        bool primero = true;
        for (Monomio monomio : polinomio)
        {
            result += monomio.ToString(primero);
            primero = false;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
};
```

Si añadimos una pequeña utilidad para interactuar con `cout`:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Polinomio const& polinomio)
{
    os << polinomio.ToString();
    return os;
}
```

Podemos comprobar cómo el código funciona correctamente ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0IYN6wclXaX8qIGh)):

```
std::cout << "f(x)=" << polinomio << '\n';
std::cout << "f'(x)=" << polinomio.Derivar() << '\n';
```

Vale, ya solo quedaría calcular el valor final. Para hacer esto vamos a dotar a la clase `Monomio` de la capacidad para calcular su valor:

```
class Monomio
{
public:
    int Calcular(int x)
    {
        return multiplicador * std::pow(x, potencia);
    }
};
```

Y ahora, `Polinomio` simplemente recorre la lista de monomios acumulando resultados:

```
class Polinomio
{
public:
    int Calcular(int x) const
    {
        int resultado = 0;
        
        for (Monomio monomio : polinomio)
        {
            resultado += monomio.Calcular(x);
        }
        
        return resultado;
    }
};
```

Y ya está, ya lo tenemos todo ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/C1Y8YBZAFv6fxi9e)):

```
Polinomio derivado = polinomio.Derivar();

std::cout << "f(x)=" << polinomio << '\n';
std::cout << "f'(x)=" << derivado << '\n';
std::cout << "f'(5)=" << derivado.Calcular(5) << '\n';
```

Ahora bien, ¿Cómo compones el polinomio con los datos que lees del archivo? No pensaba hacerte los deberes sino orientarte sobre el problema. Te toca pelearte con esa parte del problema.